# AngularJS and resource : Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $resource to show a json list file and wondering why it generates an error message :

```
 Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource
```

Here's the code :

HTML :

```
 <div ng-app="manage">
 .....

   <div class="widget-content" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{test}}
   </div>
```

app.js

```
 angular.module('manage',['ngResource']);
```

and controller.js

```
 function testCtrl($scope,$resource) {
   var dataService = $resource('/users/1/test.json');
   $scope.test = dataService.get();
 }
```

Seems it works well on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/bJfJurl6Gtw3qRcn4ViW?p=preview
But not on my app. 
I use exactly same structure.. (even on loading angular and angular-resource files order)

The only differences I can notice are angularJS version (I use 1.0.2 on my app) and of course json file.

What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE :

I changed angular versions on plunkr. Same on both side now

Comment: You have to get the same version for ngResource ! Check it ... Maybe it's so simple.

Comment: What is you version of ngResource plugin ?

Comment: ah angular-resource.js is also 1.0.2

Comment: :) also as you pointed it, I did not mention the app loads all js files (angular and co.) on bottom of the page. Could it be this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK just found it !! 
The thing is that I have 2 angular Modules in my app. On html tag I have a whole app managing Bootstrap and jQuery UI and on a specific part this module.

If we don't add ngResource on main app module, this error occurs, but then if we define this

```
<html ng-app="ui">
......
<div ng-app="manage">
```

and in Angular app.js

```
 angular.module('ui', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable', 'ngResource']);

 angular.module('manage', ['ngResource']);
```

Then it works !

I couldn't find anything in Angular Docs explaining this. But overall Big Thanks to @Thomas who helped me :)

Comment: Oh you 've got two modules lol i thought you get only one ! Accept your proper answer. But a last question : Yhe manage module is a dependency of the ui module ?

Comment: I didn't defined it as a dependancy. Should I ?